# Error: "Please provide a valid listener for purchases updates" Google Play Billing Library android

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

I'm implementing in my app the purchase of a **subscription** for the user through the **Google Play Billing Library**.

**The problem is** that I need to access the **same BillingClient instance in two different classes**:

**1. MainActivity:** I need to access the BillingClient instance to check onCreate and onResume if the user still has an active purchase or not, and then make some necessary changes to the app.

**2. BlackFragment:** here in this fragment I also need to access the BillingClient instance so that the user can purchase the subscription, if he has not yet purchased it.

With these 2 problems, I thought of the following solution:
create a **Singleton** of BillingHelper to use a single instance of BillingClient in both classes. But there's a problem here, in my MainActivity I just want to make a query to check the user's purchase and see if it's active or not, that is, for that I don't need to pass a "listener" to my instance.
In the case of BlackFragment, which will be where the user will actually make the purchase, I'll need a "listener".

And the error that is generating when accessing the MainActivity is this: *"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Please provide a valid listener for purchases updates."* This error is occurring because it is mandatory to pass a "listener" to the BillingClient instance.

How can I solve this problem, taking into account that I need to use this instance in two different classes?
Any solution?

If you need it, I'll leave the Singleton, MainActivity and BlackFragment code below:

```
object BillingHelper {
    private var billingClient: BillingClient? = null

    fun getInstance(context: Context, listener: PurchasesUpdatedListener? = null): BillingClient {
        return billingClient ?: synchronized(this) {
            billingClient ?: BillingClient.newBuilder(context)
                .apply {
                    listener?.let {
                        setListener(it)
                    }
                }
                .enablePendingPurchases()
                .build().also { billingClient = it }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   private var billingClient: BillingClient? = null

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(binding.root)
       
        billingClient = BillingHelper.getInstance(this) // error on this line
        lifecycleScope.launch { queryPurchase() }
    }

override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        lifecycleScope.launch { queryPurchase() }
    }

 override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        billingClient?.endConnection()
    }
 }
```

```
class BlackFragment : Fragment() {
   private var billingClient: BillingClient? = null
   private var purchasesUpdatedListener: PurchasesUpdatedListener? = null

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        purchasesUpdatedListener = PurchasesUpdatedListener { billingResult, purchases ->
            
            if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && purchases != null) {
                handlePurchases(purchases)
            } else if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.USER_CANCELED) {
                
                binding.root.showSnackbar("Purchase canceled")
            } else if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED) {
                binding.root.showSnackbar("Already bought")
            } else if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                binding.root.showSnackbar("Erro: FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED")
            } else {
                
                binding.root.showSnackbar("Erro: ${billingResult.debugMessage}")
            }
        }

        if (!App.isFlameBlack) { // verify if user has not purchased the product
            
            billingClient = BillingHelper.getInstance(requireContext(), purchasesUpdatedListener)
        }

        return binding.root
    }

 }
```